# How to create a music player card in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to create a card at the bottom of the screen displaying the current track playing like this example,,,,

[image]

I want to display the Track Currently Playing...and on click expand to cover the screen.

I am currently displaying the tracks to the screen like this,,,

```
 @Composable
 fun MainScreenScaffold(viewModel: TrackListViewModel){
   val context = LocalContext.current

    Scaffold(topBar = { LushTopBar(context = context) }
    ){
    MainScreenMusicList(viewModel.musicList)
   }
   }

            @Composable
            fun MainScreenMusicList(musicList: List<Track>){
            LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(0.90f)){
            item {
                musicList.forEach {
                track ->
                        TrackCard(
                            title = track.track_title,
                            Artist = track.track_artist,
                            album = track.track_album,
                            length = track.track_length,
                            isSelected = false,
                        )
                    } }
                    } }
```

I have no idea of how to make it in pure compose...any help is really appreciated

Comment: You can use a bottom sheet to achieve this: https://material.io/components/sheets-bottom

Comment: This is way too broad for a stackoverflow question, I'm afraid. You could ask for a specific component, like how to get live mediaplayer playtime and connect it to a slider, or how to make a card expand on click. You can't ask how to build an entire screen, sir. It's a net cast a little too wide.

Comment: then where to ask for such questions sir?@MARSK

Comment: @DanHarms thanks that helped...if you want you can make it an answer and ill accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a bottom sheet to achieve this.

[Component documentation](https://material.io/components/sheets-bottom)